# How to change the Bus / Dev in order to allow xsane to work

Tags: usb

I am rather new to fixing problems;  no one seems to be able to give me any guidance so I am turning to you.
I have just installed the scanner drivers for my mfc5460cn.  Everything is okay except for the connection.
lsusb shows my machine at

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f9:01b7 Brother Industries, Ltd MFC-5460CN Remote Setup

However, xsane is searching for it at Bus 1 Dev 1.

How do I reconcile this?  How can I change Bus / Dev?

Comment: The problem was solved.  lsusb to verify where the usb is located Then, sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/$Bus/$Dev

Answer (score 1):

As you stated in your comment:

The problem was solved. `lsusb` to verify where the usb is located.

Then, `sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/$Bus/$Dev`